# Is it possible to source Hive script through Git for HDInsightHive activity type in ADFv2?

Tags: azure-data-factory

This question is about ADF v2. We have activity of type HDInsightHive where script is sourced through Azure Storage. This is not very good way to source a code. It would be good if we could source this script from some existing Git repo. Is it possible? I didn't find any such option but just double checking.

Comment: Hi,any updates here?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I will accept your answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-hadoop-hive),git repo configuration is not supported for `FilePath` property in ADF Hive Activity directly.

I try to share a workaround with you that using `azure-storage-fuse` which provides a virtual filesystem backed by the Azure Blob storage.It could maps the file system directory(it could be your git repo) in your linux server to the Azure Blob Storage.Please see more details from this [github code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse).